# Google Sheets - Button link to script with a range input

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is there a way to write a script, assign it to a button, and press the button to execute the script AFTER selection a cell range that serves as an input parameter to the script in question?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are some options
About the activation, you can draw a button with "Insert-Drawing"
[image]

Then assign it a script:

[image]

Or you can set a personalized menu (see at the top right):
[image]

---

Then, you can get a value from a given cell, from the cell that is selected or from an input value. I'll give you the code for the three options and personalized menu. And the link for the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-cquJnqMbAw4ReQsYlVVx3i70IwOBqF_NMNXyHaLZco/edit?usp=sharing) for you to give it a try:

```
function from_Active() {
 var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getValue()
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("The value of the active range is: "+value)
}

function from_cell() {
 var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue()
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("The value of cell A1 is: "+value)
}

function from_prompt(){
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Insert value:")
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("The input value is: "+value)
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Values")
    .addItem("From Active","from_Active")
    .addItem("From cell","from_cell")
    .addItem("From Prompt","from_prompt")
    .addToUi()

}
```